# the make.sh for fastdht not work.When running it shows "nm: /usr/lib/libc_r.so:no such file"

Tags: dht

I want to install fastdht. So I download source code from github
https://github.com/happyfish100/fastdht

I follow the INSTALL file, run make.sh first.

```
./make.sh
```

However, it shows the following error messages.

```
[root@localhost fastdht]# sh make.sh 
make.sh: line 142: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file 
(wanted `EOF')
make.sh: line 2: ./a.out: No such file or directory
nm: '/usr/lib/libc_r.so': No such file
nm: '/lib64/libc_r.so': No such file
nm: '/usr/lib64/libc_r.so': No such file
[root@localhost fastdht]#
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some format errors in make.sh.
I create a new file a.sh and type the contents of make.sh in it. When I run a.sh it works!